# WP rest API get post by title

Tags: wordpress, wp-api, wordpress-json-api

I'm trying to check by a post title if post exist or not.
For some reason when i try something like:

```
http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[post-title]=table
```

I want if post with the name table exist, to get the post, if not,  get an empty response. But for some reason when post with title not exist i get all posts back.
How could get empty when no post exist and  the post when it exist.

Comment: I have the same issue and could not find any solution...

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately it is not possible, but you can use slug instead. Slug is editable part of the URL when writing a post and they can represent title of the page (or it can be changed into this).

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=table
```

More details:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#arguments

Answer (score 5):

According to http://v2.wp-api.org/, some have to use `search` **keyword** :
`http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=table`.

Comment: The problem is that this will return any posts that contain the keyword in the content, not just the title.

Comment: @JohnDee but you can filter the JSON out. It's better to have the result than not having it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through wp json, please copy the following code in the functions.php:

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;    
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

    $search =
    $searchand = '';

    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

Comment: So how will it be use rest api example url

Comment: Only use as follows:
your_domain_name/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=${value}

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2024

It's not well documented in the official Wordpress docs yet (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments), but you can achieve a rest api search by post title with the combination of `search` and `search_columns`. `search_columns` is an enum, though, which I've noticed after trial & error, resulting in this error message:

`search_columns[0] is not one of post_title, post_content and post_excerpt`

Example, list all posts that contain "table" in their titles, and only in their titles:

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=table&search_columns=post_title`